# grafana 2, collectd - issues with graphs

Tags: collectd, influxdb, grafana

So I have collectd running on some servers, they are sending the data back to InfluxDB. InfluxDB is storing the data, and Grafana 2 is configured with the InfluxDB as data backed - some graphs work fine - such as load average, however some doesn't graph properly - like interface statistics (see picture):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL5Mq.png

I'm guessing this is because load average is stored like so:

- `timestamp1: $current_load_average` (ex. 1.2)
- `timestamp2: $current_load_average` (ex. 1.1)

And interface statistics are stored like so:

- `timestamp1: $bytes_transfered_so_far` (ex. 1002)
- `timestamp2: $bytes_transfered_so_far` (ex. 1034)

So Grafana just graphs the total bytes that have been transferred over that interface but not the bytes/second that I need. With the same setup - when collectd was writing to RRD files and they were being graphed by several interfaces - it all worked as expected.

Can you advise what should I look into or change?

Comment: ok answered my own question:
query needs to be select derivative(value) dsname = 'tx' group by time 60s for example.

If your data is logged every 10 seconds you need to group by time 20s minimum etc.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana query might look like this:
[image: grafana query derivative]

For counters that are constantly increased you're interested in their derivation with a time window. Depends on your graph resolution (if you're looking on last day or last hour) you should choose appropriate window, where all possible peaks would be visible.

You can either use:

- `Transformation > derivative()`
- `Transformation > non_negative_derivative()`

The latter is useful in cases where you want to omit negative values from your chart.